# Select subset of rows of numpy array based on a selection of rows in another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays and I wanted to select a subset of rows in one of them based on a conditional subset of the other

```
arr1 = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 5], [3, 4, 1, 6], [2, 2, 2, 7]])
arr2 = np.array([[2, 2, 1], [2, 3, 0], [2, 1, 1]])
```

I want to select only those rows in `arr1` where the 3rd element in `arr2` is 1. In this case, `arr2` will look like so:
`np.array([[2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]])` and `arr1` will become: `np.array([[1, 2, 1, 5], [2, 2, 2, 7]])`. Both of them can be assumed to have the same number of rows, but can have different number of columns. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [500]: arr2
Out[500]: 
array([[2, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 0],
       [2, 1, 1]])
```

3rd element of each row:

```
In [502]: arr2[:,2]
Out[502]: array([1, 0, 1])
In [503]: arr2[:,2]==1
Out[503]: array([ True, False,  True])
```

apply this boolean mask to select rows of arr1:

```
In [504]: arr1[arr2[:,2]==1]
Out[504]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 5],
       [2, 2, 2, 7]])
```